# How to show transitionDuration in css animation?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations, transition

**Fiddle A:**

I have a gallery of images **(there are 4 right now)** as shown here in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vj3pb8xd/embedded/result) (lets call as **Fiddle A**) 
in which every single image fades out after 3s second and there is transition delay of 800ms.

I have used JS to make the animation work. In JS, I have used the following constants in my JS.

- `transitionDuration` => is the delay (white flash which we see) which happens on moving from one image to another.
- `transitionDelay` => is the presenation time of an image (meaning the time span for which the image stay at their place).
- `totalDelay` => is only for one image.

**Fiddle B:**

I also have another gallery of images as shown in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8gtzeonc/) (let's call as **Fiddle B**)  in which a CSS animation is going on.

Presentation time of one image in the fiddle is 3 seconds, and then it moves to another images.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make in **Fiddle B** so that it looks like Fiddle A. In Fiddle B there is no `transitionDuration`. Is there a way we can add a `transitionDuration` (white flash which we can 
see on moving from one image to another)?

In **Fiddle B**, I have used the following CSS:

```
a:nth-of-type(4), .featured-block a:nth-of-type(5), .featured-block a:nth-of-type(6) { 
  position: absolute; 
  animation: 9s infinite ease-in-out cf4FadeInOut;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: @Aleksander Ciecierski Hi, sorry about that. I am wondering if you can suggest a edit. By mistake, your previous edit got rejected.

Comment: Yeah... I've noticed, I spent 20 minutes wondering what your post was all about :/

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting opacity in keyframes to achieve transition duration works, which you have implemented.

Remove `opacity: 1` and `opacity: 0` so that it becomes

```
.featured-block a { display: inline-block; } 

a:nth-of-type(4), .featured-block a:nth-of-type(5), .featured-block a:nth-of-type(6) { 
  position: absolute; 
  animation: 3s infinite ease-in-out cf4FadeInOut;
  z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I saw the fiddle. Its not working properly. On page-load, **Picture 4** should show up and then after few seconds **Picture 5** and then **Picture 6**.

Comment: Let me know it makes sense.